# DataGridview agrgar formato a celdas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Quiero hacer que las celdas de un dataGridview sean formato moneda lo he hecho por medio de codigo y con la interfaz de forms de visual pero no aplica el formato no se si es devido a que el datatable donde provienen los datos lo actualizo con un boton y eso varia el gridview o no puedo darle formato a los datos de una data Table aplico el formato asi:

```
DGV.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
```

y con un boton cambio la información tiene la siguiente función:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count==0) {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{dias,septimo,totaldias,horasE,horasP,valorSep,ordinario,extra,devengado,
                valorP,iggs,prestamo,descuento,liquido,bonDecreto,variable,ajuste,total });
           
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows.Clear();
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{dias,septimo,totaldias,horasE,horasP,valorSep,ordinario,extra,devengado,
                valorP,iggs,prestamo,liquido,bonDecreto,descuento,variable,ajuste,total });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hice pruebas y el formato es aplicado sin importar si lo asigno vía código o via interfaz de propiedades del DataGridView.

Por favor revisa la declaración de las variables que agregas en cada columna y asegurate que las que quieras mostrar con formato de moneda sean de un tipo de datos numérico como `int`, `Decimal`, etc.  porque si son de tipo `string` o un `object` que contiene `string` no le será aplicado el formato.

Por ejemplo:

```
string devengado = "1530";  //a esta NO se le aplica formato
decimal devengado = 1530;   //a esta SI se le aplica formato
```