# Dar Formato de separación de miles y decimales C#

Tags: c#, datatable, formato

Estoy tratando de que el resultante de esta multiplicacion tome formato "1.234,00" pero el formato no es visible en la grilla.

```
double tp = Math.Round(vEstimada * precio);
 
row["Total Periodo"] = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", tp);
```

**este dato está dentro de un foreach de un datatable.**

Comment: que valor tiene originalmente antes de convertirlo a "1.234,00" ?

Comment: @Jorgesys 365762.0

Comment: y ese dato como deseas que sea formateado.

Comment: @Jorgesys Así 365.762,00

Comment: quizas debas primero cambiar el datatype a String antes de asignar el formato.
row["Total Periodo"].DataType = typeof(String);
row["Total Periodo"] = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", tp);

Comment: @IgnacioC. si cambias de 365762.0  a 365.762,00 no indicaría en realidad la misma cantidad es como si dijeras que 100.00 es igual a 10.0 el punto indicaría una cifra definitivamente diferente, revisa lo que comento en mi respuesta , saludos.

Comment: En caso de que el componente que llamas grilla sea un `DataGridView`, tal vez [este caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/379098/182188) sea de utilidad. Ver pregunta y respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

si deseas convertir por ejemplo de:

```
365762.0
```

a el valor:

```
365.762,00
```

esto podría no ser correcto ya que el valor ya no es el mismo, para indicar miles usa coma y no punto, debería ser:

```
365,762.00
```

Si deseas realizar esto puedes usar `tp.ToString("n2")` :

```
row["Total Periodo"] = tp.ToString("n2");
```

o usar `String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", tp)` :

```
row["Total Periodo"] = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", tp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que el número tome el formato tal que "1.234,00" podemos hacer uso de los métodos del objeto string, para ello usaré un método que se encarga de formatearlo:

```
// Al método se le pasa una cadena numérica con formato "1,234.00" y
// el método devolverá una cadena numérica con formato: "1.234,00"
public string GetOwnFormat(string p_StrNumber)
{
     string strResult = p_StrNumber.Replace(",", "#").Replace(".", ",").Replace("#", ".");

     return strResult;
}
```

En tu código basta que hagas la llamada al método así:

```
double tp = Math.Round(vEstimada * precio);
string strNumber = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", tp);

row["Total Periodo"] = GetOwnFormat(strNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba usando cultureinfo.CurrentCulture
Crear metodos solamente para dar formatos no creo que sea lo mas conveniente en estos casos.

```
 double value = 12345.6789;
 row["Total Periodo"] = value.ToString("C3",
              CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"));
//El ejemplo mostrara la siguiente salida.
//       12.345,679 kr
```

Aqui te dejo el link para que puedas leer mas [Standard numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)